# Пересечение прямоугольников. Python

Tags: python

> С клавиатуры на двух строчках через пробел вводятся координаты левого верхнего угла и размеры (ширина и высота) двух прямоугольников. На первой строке параметры одного прямоугольника, на второй — второго.
>
> Программа должна выводить YES, если прямоугольники пересекаются или касаются друг друга (то есть имеют хотя бы одну общую точку) и NO в противном случае.

Как это определить?

Comment: при помощи математики

Comment: http://cpp.mazurok.com/tag/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/ . Думаю, сможете "перевести" на пайтон.

Comment: В чём именно ваш вопрос? Вы не понимаете геометрического смысла задачи или у вас затруднение в написании кода? Если затруднение в коде - то какое именно?

Comment: Как рассматривать случай когда один из прямоугольников целиком лежит в другом, не пересекая его и не касаясь? Другими словами как понимать фразу `"имеют хотя бы одну общую точку"` - рассмартиваем точки только лежащие на сторонах прямоугольников или все точки внутри тоже?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: картинка пересечения двух прямоугольников]

```
# решение в Python

def is_cross(a,b):
    ax1,ay1,ax2,ay2 = a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]          # прямоугольник А 
    bx1, by1, bx2, by2 = b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]    # прямоугольник B
    # это были координаты точек диагонали по каждому прямоугольнику

    # 1. Проверить условия перекрытия, например, если XПA<XЛB , 
    #    то прямоугольники не пересекаются,и общая площадь равна нулю.
    #   (это случай, когда они справа и слева) и аналогично, если они сверху
    #    и снизу относительно друг друга.   
    #    (XПА - это  Х Правой точки прямоугольника А)
    #    (ХЛВ - Х Левой точки прямоугольника В )
    #    нарисуй картинку (должно стать понятнее)

    xA = [ax1,ax2]  # координаты x обеих точек прямоугольника А
    xB = [bx1,bx2]  # координаты x обеих точке прямоугольника В

    yA = [ay1, ay2]  # координаты x обеих точек прямоугольника А
    yB = [by1, by2]  # координаты x обеих точек прямоугольника В

    if max(xA)<min(xB) or max(yA) < min(yB) or min(yA) > max(yB):
        return False    # не пересекаются

    # 2. Определить стороны прямоугольника образованного пересечением,
    # например,
    # если XПA>XЛB, а XЛA<XЛB, то ΔX=XПA−XЛB

    elif max(xA)>min(xB) and min(xA)<min(xB):
        dx = max(xA)-min(xB)
        return True     # пересекаются
    else:
        return True     # пересекаются


    # 3. далее уже можно определить площадь, как произведение сторон: 
         SAB=ΔX∗ΔY



#тесты    

#result = is_cross([-5, 2, 3,-2], [2, 6, 5, 1])
#print(result, "test 1")  #True

#result = is_cross([1, 4, 6, 1], [5, 5, 7, 3])
#print(result, "test 2")  #True

#result = is_cross([5, 5, 7, 3], [1, 4, 6, 1])
#print(result, "test 3")   #True

#result = is_cross([-2, 3, 0, -2], [0, -2, 2, -4])
#print(result, "test 4")   #True

#result = is_cross([0, -2, 2, -4], [-2, 3, 0, -2])
#print(result, "test 5")   #True

#result = is_cross([2, 5, 6, 1], [3, 4, 5, 2])
#print(result, "test 6")   #True

#result = is_cross([3, 4, 5, 2], [2, 5, 6, 1])
#print(result, "test 7")   #True

#result = is_cross([1, 4, 4, 2], [1, 1, 4, -1])
#print(result, "test 8")   #True

#result = is_cross([1, 1, 4, -1], [1, 4, 4, 2])
#print(result, "test 9")   #False

#result = is_cross([-5, 1, 5, -1], [-1, 5, 1, -5])
#print(result, "test 11")   #True
```

Comment: Входные данные не соответствуют условиям задачи. А еще совершенно ненужное условие elif.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте:

```
ax1, ay1, ax2, ay2 = [ int(i) for i in input("1-й прямоугольник - x y w h: ").split() ]
ax2 = ax1 + ax2
ay2 = ay1 + ay2

bx1, by1, bx2, by2 = [ int(i) for i in input("2-й прямоугольник - x y w h: ").split() ]
bx2 = bx1 + bx2
by2 = by1 + by2

s1 = ( ax1>=bx1 and ax1<=bx2 ) or ( ax2>=bx1 and ax2<=bx2 )
s2 = ( ay1>=by1 and ay1<=by2 ) or ( ay2>=by1 and ay2<=by2 )
s3 = ( bx1>=ax1 and bx1<=ax2 ) or ( bx2>=ax1 and bx2<=ax2 )
s4 = ( by1>=ay1 and by1<=ay2 ) or ( by2>=ay1 and by2<=ay2 )

print( "YES" if ((s1 and s2) or (s3 and s4)) or ((s1 and s4) or (s3 and s2)) else "NO" )
```

---

```
1-й прямоугольник - x y w h: 10 10 200 200
2-й прямоугольник - x y w h: 210 210 10 10
YES
```

---

```
1-й прямоугольник - x y w h: 10 10 200 200
2-й прямоугольник - x y w h: 211 210 10 10
NO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_intersection(el, rect):
    return rect[0] <= el[0] <= rect[3] and rect[1] <= el[1] <= rect[2] or \
           rect[0] <= el[3] <= rect[3] and rect[1] <= el[1] <= rect[2] or \
           rect[0] <= el[0] <= rect[3] and rect[1] <= el[2] <= rect[2] or \
           rect[0] <= el[3] <= rect[3] and rect[1] <= el[2] <= rect[2]
```

el состоит из (x0,y0,x1,y1) как и rect

Answer (score -2):

```
def is_cross(a, b):
    ax1, ay1, ax2, ay2 = a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]
    bx1, by1, bx2, by2 = b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]

    aXRange = []
    aYRange = []
    bXRange = []
    bYRange = []

    for x in range(ax1, ax2 + 1):
        aXRange.append(x)

    for y in range(ay2, ay1 + 1):
        aYRange.append(y)

    for x in range(bx1, bx2 + 1):
        bXRange.append(x)

    for y in range(by2, by1 + 1):
        bYRange.append(y)

    commonPointOnX = list(set(aXRange) & set(bXRange))
    commonPointOnY = list(set(aYRange) & set(bYRange))

    return commonPointOnX != [] and commonPointOnY != []
```